# Obtaining geographic points with CSV file

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a xlsx file with a column called CoordX and another with CoordY, I save the file in CSV format (semi-colon) and use the delimited text plugin and follow all the information in the text box.

But QGIS doesn't find the data, which are "recognize" as belonging to the first line.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In input form, you have to specify which column is X and which is Y.

You should also check which CRS gets assigned to the layer (if you are not asked).

EPSG:4326 WGS84 can only have lat/lon degrees up to +/- 180/90, so cioordinates in metres will exceed the limit in most cases.